# Deixar de "falar bonito" ou ser simples nas respostas é motivo para tomar negativos?

Tags: debate, respostas, voto-contra

Eu viz uma pergunta aqui [Qual é a diferença entre o método PUT e o POST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92870/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-m%C3%A9todo-put-e-o-post) e achei interessante é que uma resposta que estava certa tomou negativos, simplesmente porque a resposta pareceu ser simples demais.

E daí? Respostas simples e diretas não são respostas?

Questionei o motivo de o rapaz ser negativado por sua resposta, mas não apareceu ninguém para explicar.

Segue o link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92877/4995

É por isso que pergunto: Falar de maneira informal ou ser simples demais é motivo para tomar negativos?

Comment: Não sei, já vi umas respostas "mais simples" no SOen (recentemente) de usuários com pontuação alta, a resposta geralmente é mais um comentário (com link ou não). No entanto ganham bastante votos (nem sei o motivo), eu acredito que os negativos não sejam por erro ou por só ser simples, mas por falta de uma "referencia" ou "fonte". Veja este caso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92875/3635 o usuário colocou ao menos uma fonte (mesmo sendo do SOen)... Eu vou dizer, não acho justo, mas também não acho injusto...

Comment: ... **acho** que os votos ali foram parciais e de opinião pessoal. Não tem como saber o motivo dos votos. Infelizmente não tem muito o que brigar, eu mesmo postei uma resposta bem simples aqui no SOpt, no entanto não ganhei votos negativos, mas as demais estavam melhores, provavelmente os votos foram de usuários que queriam evidenciar outras respostas que pareciam melhor e mais detalhada que a dele e não pra dizer que a dele é ruim.

Comment: Eu acho que aqui no SOPT rola muitos pontos positivos (ou negativos) simplesmente por ser "um rosto conhecido"

Comment: Pode ser até em alguns casos, mas neste não parece, parece mesmo pra "subir" as mais completas (ficar no topo), algo como preferenciar respostas melhores, não acho certo, mas com certeza uma resposta *mais trabalhada* ali por parte dele teria evitado isto. Eu vou até lançar um upvote pra ele, mas acho que ele poderia melhorar ou até citar uma fonte.

Comment: Nesse caso, @GuilhermeNascimento, eu não daria nem positivo nem negativo. Acho que negativo é quando algo está errado. Quando está certo,não tem por que negativar!

Comment: Como eu disse a falta de fonte ou detalhes são fatores que alguns podem considerar como errado na resposta e isto é que leva as vezes a tomarmos downvotes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92870/qual-é-a-diferença-entre-o-método-put-e-o-post/92877#comment188678_92877

Answer (score 9):

Existem muitos fatores que levam as pessoas acharem a resposta *errada* (ou melhor dizendo *ruim*).

### Respostas erradas

As respostas que tem evidencia de estar incorreta geralmente são sinalizadas ou fechadas (se tiver pontos pra isto) e podem ser negativadas ou não.

### Respostas ruims (ou fracas)

Acho que aqui é que cai o caso do nosso colega, a resposta ***não*** é errada, mas isto não quer dizer que seja uma resposta boa ou confiável (não estou desmerecendo a resposta dele é apenas uma possível explicação), problemas em respostas que costumam tornar a resposta *ruim* (e com isto acabam ganhando alguns votos negativos) são:

1. Falta de fonte confiável
2. Falta de detalhamento
3. Falta de organização por tópico e de marcação do texto fazendo ela parecer um comentário e não uma resposta

No caso a resposta do autor tem o primeiro e o terceiro problema, não que isto torne uma resposta ruim de verdade, mas devemos deixar claro que a resposta sempre pode melhorar, isto **NÃO** é uma obrigação e nem um requisito de qualidade da SE, no entanto cada comunidade e cada pessoa participativa na comunidade acaba formando uma ideia de qualidade.

Neste caso tomar um voto negativo parece errado para alguns e certo para outros, mas acho que neste caso especifico do autor ele poderia ter evitado apenas citando uma fonte (acredito eu), sendo que o provável motivo que o levou a `-2` foi as pessoas notarem maior esforço por parte dos demais usuários do a dele.

<sub>(talvez tenha sido um puxão de orelha ou dois *~ cada voto um puxão de orelha, pra quem não entendeu a referencia*)</sub>

As pessoas provavelmente não comentam (criticam) postagens pois tem medo de *retalhamento*, devido a imaturidade que alguns usuários demonstram aqui.

### Conclusão

- Se puder melhorar a sua resposta, então **MELHORE**
- Se souber a resposta de cabeça ainda sim pesquise uma fonte pra tornar a sua resposta melhor
- Se for o caso de um código, forneça ao menos um código minimo de exemplo
- Não existe exigência para tal qualidade, mas não quer dizer que não podemos melhorar o nosso próprio trabalho
- Se puder torne *não apenas* as perguntas relevantes pra outros usuários, mas as respostas também

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente suas colocações.Continua achando que deixá-lo apenas "zerado" era melhor que dá negativos. Na verdade, o problema é que temos que advinhar os negativos, já que as pessoas são rápidas para negativas, mas lentas para fazer críticas construtivas.

Comment: Gostei da questão da "imaturidade". Realmente, até eu as vezes tenho medo de fazer que fui eu que negativei e o cara não largar mais do meu pé

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Chamei o colega pra participar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92870/qual-é-a-diferença-entre-o-método-put-e-o-post/92877#comment188689_92877

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a falta de feedback por -1 atrapalha bastante, tanto as respostas como as perguntas, meu ponto de vista é que tem usuários que quando vê resposta com muitos -1s ele negativa sem lê a mesma, parecido com comportamento de manada.

Comment: Desculpe @DenerCarvalho eu discordo, acho que poucos votos negativos sejam por falta de quem esta negativando ler (raros), a maior parte dos votos negativos sem comentário são por medo de serem retalhados, eu já conversei com outras pessoas que pensavam como você, mas te digo de certo uma coisa, após um certo tempo de experiencia no SOpt ou no SOen, você irá notar sérios problemas em postagens que antes você não notava. Veja esta resposta minha, antigamente o pessoal tinha um certo preconceito com Suspender (hoje chamado de pendente) perguntas: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: Não estou dizendo que não existe o *voto manada*, mas raramente o primeiro voto negativo dificilmente foi por falta de leitura de quem negativou e nem todas vezes os votos são de "manadas". @DenerCarvalho

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu não quis dizer o primeiro voto, sempre quando aparece perguntas com 1 ou 4 votos negativos a pergunta não esta clara o suficiente ou não esta de acordo com a política do site. Porem, eu ja vi perguntas simples e bem claras receberem muitos votos negativos em pouco tempo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento também entendo seu ponto de vista, que uma parte da falta de feedback é por medo de retaliação, porem msm assim se o usuário da um -1 na pergunta ou na resposta ele já esta tendo uma atitude errada em não informar o motivo do -1, e também o usuário que decidir perseguir alguém só por causa de um -1.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho é como eu disse pode parecer que o voto negativo é injusto e talvez pra você até parece uma pergunta clara, mas é provável que debaixo da simplicidade exista mais problemas do que aparenta e ou mesmo você percebeu e alguns usuários mais experientes percebem algo que talvez você não tenha percebido. Não quero dizer que todos são justos, mas em grande maioria são sim.

Comment: @Dener, comentário para -1 **não é** obrigatório nem muito menos "atitude errada". Imagino que você discorda, mas isso já foi discutido à exaustão em *todos* os metas de *todos* os sites, decisão: votar é livre e o comentário é opcional.